# Using p4 api to view the files of a pending changelist

Tags: c#, perforce, changelist

I would like to be able to output the files of any given pending changelist.  The only property in the p4 api that seems close is Changelist.Files, but this returns a list of FileMetaData and not the files themselves.

Another interesting thing that may or may not be relevant is that upon running...

```
Console.WriteLine(changelist);
```

...I get a description of the changelist such as client, user, status, etc, but in the "Files" field, there is never any files listed.  Not sure if this because the files have not been added to the depot yet, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean the **contents** of the files in the pending changelist, rather than just the **names** of the files? You can't access the contents until after the changelist is submitted (or shelved), because until then the files are stored only on the user's workstation.

Comment: I am just trying to access the file names using the API.

Comment: Another peculiar thing is that when I run changelist.Files.Count it returns 0, as if there are no files in the changelist...but I am positive the changelist has files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
var changes = rep.GetChangelists(new Options(ChangesCmdFlags.FullDescription, null, -1, ChangeListStatus.Pending, con.UserName));
foreach (var change in changes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(change.Id);
    GetOpenedFilesOptions getOpenedFiles = new GetOpenedFilesOptions(GetOpenedFilesCmdFlags.None, change.Id.ToString(), con.Client.Name, con.UserName, -1);
    IList<Perforce.P4.File> fileList = rep.GetOpenedFiles(null, getOpenedFiles);
    foreach (var f in fileList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
}
```

This will go through the pending changelists and output their ID# and file names.  The arguments of GetOpenedFilesOptions allows you to restrict your search to a particular client, user, or both.  Additionally, it may be helpful to know that you can restrict your search further by file name or directory by including a FileSpec argument in rep.GetChangelists.